# Cannot connect 18B20+ to raspberry pi 3

Tags: pi-3, ds18b20

I will try connect 18B20+ termomether to raspberry pi 3.

It's how i do that:
[image: IMG]

In /boot/config.txt i add:

> dtoverlay=w1-gpio

After reboot in console, as root, I

> modprobe w1-gpio
>
> modprobe w1-therm

But after

> ls /sys/bus/w1/devices/

directories list are empty.

Any ideas?

Comment: Yeah, you right ;p. I set bad pin in fritzing.

Comment: You should not need the modprobes.  That is automatically done by the dtoverlay in /boot/config.txt.  A photo of your connections will be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, problem was solved by type in /boot/config.txt

> dtoverlay=w1-gpio,gpiopin=4